# How to parse binary data transmitted over GPIB with IVI library

Tags: c#, visa

I am working with a Fluke 8588 and communicating with it using `Ivi.Visa.Interop` I am trying to use the digitizer function to get a large number of samples of a 5V 1k Hz sinewave. To improve the transfer time of the data the manual mentions a setting for using a binary packed data format. It provides 2 and 4 byte packing.

This is the smallest example I could put together:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Ivi.Visa.Interop;

namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Initiallizing Equipment");

            int timeOut = 3000;
            string resourceName = "GPIB0::1::INSTR";

            ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager();
            FormattedIO488 fluke8588 = new FormattedIO488
            {
                IO = (IMessage)rm.Open(resourceName, AccessMode.NO_LOCK, timeOut)
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Starting Setup");
            fluke8588.WriteString("FORMAT:DATA PACKED,4");
            fluke8588.WriteString("TRIGGER:COUNT 100000");

            Console.WriteLine("Initiate Readings");
            fluke8588.WriteString("INITIATE:IMMEDIATE");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            Console.WriteLine("Readings Complete");

            Console.WriteLine("Fetching Reading");
            fluke8588.WriteString("FETCH?");
            string response = fluke8588.ReadString();

            Byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
            fluke8588.WriteString("FORMAT:DATA:SCALE?");
            double scale = Convert.ToDouble(fluke8588.ReadString());

            int parityMask = 0x8;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i += 4)
            {
                int raw = (int)((bytes[i] << 24) | (bytes[i + 1] << 16) | (bytes[i + 2] << 8) | (bytes[i + 3]));
                int parity = (parityMask & bytes[i]) == parityMask ? -1 : 1;

                int number = raw;
                if (parity == -1)
                {
                    number = ~raw * parity;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(number * scale);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting data looks like this:

[image]

---

I preformed the steps "manually" using a tool called NI Max. I get a header followed by the 10 4 byte integers and ending with a new line char. the negative integers are 2s complement, which was not specified in the manual but I was able to determine after I had enough samples.

[image: NI Max]

`TRIGGER:COUNT` was only set to 10 at the time this image was taken.

[image]

**How can I get this result in c#?**

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was using the wrong Encoding, changing from `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response)` to

```cs
System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(response);
```

got the desired result.

---

That said, I also learned there is an alternative option to `FormattedIO488.ReadString` for binary data, using `FormattedIO488.ReadIEEEBlock(IEEEBinaryType.BinaryType_I4)` this will return an array of integers and requires no extra effort with twiddling bits, this is the solution I would suggest.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Ivi.Visa.Interop;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Initiallizing Equipment");

            int timeOut = 3000;
            string resourceName = "GPIB0::1::INSTR";

            ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager();
            FormattedIO488 fluke8588 = new FormattedIO488
            {
                IO = (IMessage)rm.Open(resourceName, AccessMode.NO_LOCK, timeOut)
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Starting Setup");
            fluke8588.WriteString("FORMAT:DATA PACKED,4");
            fluke8588.WriteString("TRIGGER:COUNT 100000");

            Console.WriteLine("Initiate Readings");
            fluke8588.WriteString("INITIATE:IMMEDIATE");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            Console.WriteLine("Readings Complete");

            Console.WriteLine("Fetching Reading");
            fluke8588.WriteString("FETCH?");
            List<int> response = new List<int>(fluke8588.ReadIEEEBlock(IEEEBinaryType.BinaryType_I4));

            fluke8588.WriteString("FORMAT:DATA:SCALE?");
            double scale = Convert.ToDouble(fluke8588.ReadString());
            foreach (var value in response.Select(i => i * scale).ToList())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Result data looks like:

[image]

Comment: Depending on the platform the default encoding could change, it is better to find out what was the default encoding and use it, so your code behaves consistent across different platforms

Comment: @Cleptus I tried all the text encoding options under `System.Text.Encoding` and only Default works, I believe that is because it does a "best-fit" for unsupported chars

Comment: Strange, usually one encoding matches, [Encoding.Default Property documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=net-5.0) suggests avoiding using `Encoding.Default`. Have you tried looking what does `Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.Default.WebName)` return?

Comment: @Cleptus Looks like my default is `Windows-1252`, using that encoding did work so I have updated my answer. Thank you! this was exactly why I decided to make this post I knew I still had something to learn from this issue.